# `root` vs `sudo` from ulimit POV

Tags: sudo, ulimit

According some other questions and answers, I expected the same results for both commands, but that's not the case.

furthermore, running a process from sudo, terminated with "too many open files", where running as root didn't.
What is the difference exactly between the 2 ?

```
nati@server:/var/tmp$ sudo bash  -c "ulimit -n"
1024
nati@server:/var/tmp$ sudo su
root@server:/var/tmp# ulimit -n
32000
```

Comment: `ulimit -n` tells you the limit on open files without `grep`.

Comment: @countermode - Thanks, I'll update the question, but the results are the same...

Comment: what kind of system is this? I checked over here, and `ulimit -n` outputs 1024 for root and non-root on two different distros. Apparently, there's something configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf` - please check.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 14.04. obviously that's after `/etc/security/limits.conf` was configured with `root soft  nofile 32000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is used by `pam_limits`. An authentication module such as `su`, `sudo`, or `login` invokes PAM modules according to the PAM description. For most distros that means to pick up the according entry in `/etc/pam.d/`. For instance, this may be `/etc/pam.d/sudo`; for Gentoo that looks like

```
auth    include         system-auth
account include         system-auth
session include         system-auth
```

where `system-auth` has a line like

```
session         required        pam_limits.so
```

Therefore, the resource limits are configured as defined in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

For my Kali installation, that looks different. `pam_limits` is not invoked for `sudo`. Apparently, all Debian anchestors share this "feature". Experimenting with `/etc/security/limits.conf` confirms your observation - on `sudo` I get 1024 while for login I get what I configured in `limits.conf`.

Comment: Cool ! thanks. but where exactly did you see that `pam_limits.so` is invoked for `sudo` ?

Comment: You just need to follow all `include` directives. In the example above for Gentoo that means to look up `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, where indeed `pam_limits` is invoked.